# Nutch - Could not load definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, nutch

I'm learning  [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) through the official guide. So when I run  [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) at bin directory, it says:

> "Could not load definitions from resource `org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml`. It
>   could not be found."

I've spent a lot of time in google to solve it, but I failed. My OS is Ubuntu16.04.

[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to comment all this part in `build.xml`:

```
  <!-- ================================================================== -->
  <!-- SONAR targets                                                      -->
  <!-- ================================================================== -->

  <!-- Define the Sonar task if this hasn't been done in a common script -->
  <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${ant.library.dir}"/>
    <classpath path="${mysql.library.dir}"/>
  </taskdef>

  <!-- Add the target -->
  <target name="sonar" description="--> run SONAR analysis">

    <!-- list of mandatory source directories (required) -->
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="${src.dir}"/>

    <!-- list of properties (optional) -->
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="Nutch Trunk 1.4 Sonar Analysis" />
    <property name="sonar.binaries" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="sonar.binaries" value="${build.dir}/plugins" />
    <property name="sonar.tests" value="${test.src.dir}" />

    <sonar:sonar workDir="${base.dir}" key="org.apache.nutch:trunk" 
     version="1.4-SNAPSHOT" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>
  </target>
```

in this way, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is an old one, but felt the answer might help someone else.

Setting sonarqube for java ant project with configuration specified in [sonarqube-setup-for-ant](https://pmpl.cs.ui.ac.id/sonarqube/documentation/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-ant/#use) throws error 'could not fine exception...'

Solution: try replacing the '*' defined in the

```
<classpath path="/usr/share/ant/lib/sonarqube-ant-task-*.jar" />
```

Target tag:

```
<target name="sonar">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonarqube-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
        <classpath path="path/to/sonar/ant/task/lib/sonarqube-ant-task-*.jar" />
    </taskdef>
 
    <!-- Execute SonarScanner for Ant Analysis -->
    <sonar:sonar />
</target>
```